# PHP / CURL / JSON / AJAX / HTML - can not retrieve what i need

Tags: php, html, ajax, json, curl

I have server 1 and server 2. I need that i will post data from server 2 to server 1 to fill up the form and submit it without redirecting the user to server 1, and after the form is submitted i need that the PHP from server 1 will be executed and send back to server 2 the result of submitting form.

Maybe will be more clear with the code below:

By the way, the form are in ajax.

PHP from server 2:

```
$url_base = 'the_path_of_the url_of_the_form_frontend_file_server_1.php';
$url_param =
            'name=' . $_USER['name'] .
            '&email=' . $_USER['email'] .
            '&phone=' . $_USER['phone'] .
            '&country=' . $_USER['country'].
            '&password=' . $_USER['password'] .
            '&verify_code=' . '-' .
            '&group=' . 1 .
            '&leverage=' . 100 .
            '&deposit=' . 10000 .
            '&state=' . '-' .
            '&zipcode=' . '-' .
            '&city=' . '-' .
            '&phone_password=' . '-' .
            '&send_reports=' . '-' .
            '&register_demo=' . 'yes_register';



$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_base);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $url_param);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($url_param))
);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

My code is sending data from server 2 to server 1 and completing the form and the $result is displaying the html of the form, but i need that after the form is submitted from server 2 to server 1, i need that the php of the form from server 1 will be executed and send back the result of the form, actually after the form is submitted the result will be a login and a password for the user, the login and password is created after the form is submitted.

I am sending an extra parameter this one '&register_demo=' . 'yes_register'; to identify when the form is completed from server 1, my form have 2 files one file for front-end and another one for the back-end because i use ajax.

If i do not make a mistake seems after the form is submitted from server 2 to server 1 i get result OK but seems the php is not executed on the server 1 that i can retrieve back the login and password. And i try to GET this parameter '&register_demo=' . 'yes_register'; is doing nothing, seems that form is only submitted and not going to the back-end file.

Please i will appreciate a lot for any help, this situation is getting me crazy.

I came out with this solution because the form can be submitted only from one IP, and because of this i have the same form on another server, i need somehow to submit the form from server 2 and get the login and password to the server 2 to display it to the user.

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: No idea what you are actually trying to achieve here, but a few key words jump out at me. You cannot interact with javascript via curl, so thats probably your issue. If you manage both servers, you should just write an api on server1 that server2 can consume

Comment: @user574632 So u mean because i use AJAX and after i send post to server 1 is submitting the form and is not calling the back end for that form because of jquery?

Comment: Yes, thats my **guess** here. And its only a guess, but an educated one! The key point here, is that you shouldnt be using curl to interact with html forms that are designed for users with a browser if you own both servers - create a proper api that is designed to consumed in code.

Comment: You need to send the CURL request to the backend file of server 1 not to the frontend file which contains the form markup and javascript I think. An ajax request is very similar to a CURL request. Both are request. ajax is for client side requests and CURL for server side request. So both: the ajax request of server 1 and the CURL request of server 2 to server 1 should have the same origin file (which is the backend file of server 1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments to my question i managed to find a solution.

I will describe the solution below, and if someone need help i can help to sort it out.

Solution:

Because of my form is using AJAX, i was sending curl from server 2 to server 1 to complete the form and get the result after the PHP will be executed on server 1. Because of AJAX my PHP was not executed.

So i created an API that server 2 will consume it. I implemented the form in a different file and all the PHP that i need to be executed (plane PHP). After that i was sending the CURL to that API i did and PHP start to be executed and returning the desired result.

If someone need more help about this, please contact me and i can help, or i can put sample of code based on your request.

Thanks guys for the correct hints.

Comment: Can you please put sample code for the above type of request.